# Firefox 22+ displaying extremely large font

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-size

I'm working on a website and Firefox is displaying it's font extremely large. Chrome and Safari are displaying normal font size. I've found that you can change font display by typing

```
about:config
```

in the firefox address bar and changing the

```
 layout.css.devPixelsPerPx
```

value to 1. Although this might work on some systems, I don't want my user to need to do this.

How can I make sure that the font is displayed correctly? I've tried adjusting CSS with

```
-moz-font-size
```

and variants but it doesn't work. Is there a specific syntax for this?

Comment: This is a system issue and not a Firefox issue. Users should not encounter this problem normally. If you really must use a hack, I'm not sure if the resolution media queries would work.

Comment: Try ctr+0 maybe you just zoomed in in FF?

Comment: I'm on a mac retina display but I've tested on windows systems with normal and 10 inch screens and problem reproduces while other browsers display normally.

Comment: Is it specific to your website ? Maybe there is some javascript that changes the font-size so ?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67752/firefox-22-large-font-workaround/67762